# file_get_contents not working as expected

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Several years ago, I designed my website with a wordpress installation in a subfolder named 'wp'. I wanted to my site to have wordpress as the main page, so I changed my site's home page, 'index.php', to contain the following:

```
<?php 
$filename="http://www.example.com/wp/index.php";
$file= file_get_contents($filename);
echo $file;
?>
```

This was supposed to mirror my wordpress home page.
It used to work, but now is just blank. What is causing this?

Comment: It's impossible to say without any errors. Is your server actually up if you request it directly? Do you have errors enabled in your php config to see the errors? Do you get anything logged in your php errors file?

Comment: Why don't you just configure the http-server to use the `wp` directory as root?

Comment: Perhaps server config has changed to dissallow file_get_contents, so if it's on the same server I'd expect it to work if you use the files folder location instead, eg .'/var/home/www/wp/index.php' or something like that. I havn't tested it or used the function in a while, so not too sure about this.

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to say without full information, but the most common reason for that is ini-setting **allow_url_fopen** - if set to `Off`, `No` or `0` it will forbid getting the page in this way.

Please get the value of this ini-setting for us. The most easy way to do this would be:

```
echo 'allow_url_fopen = ', ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
```

This setting cannot be changed with `ini_set()`, since it has a `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` changeability.

Comment: Should it be a strictly-PHP solution? Most http-servers have redirects (it is mod_rewrite for Apache2, not sure about others). I can give you instructions on how to solve the issue if you have Apache 2.4.x